# what does code does? and what is this syntax: list(board[r,:])?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

First question about all that code ..I can't get the this code or know what is the output of it?

Second question about list in the second for loop--it's a first time i see this syntax to a list and can't understand how it works. `list(board[r,:]`)

```
ROW_COUNT = 7
COLUMN_COUNT = 7

board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT))

for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
    row_array = [int(i) for i in list(board[r,:])]
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        window = row_array[c:c+WINDOW_LENGTH]
```

Comment: That's numpy array syntax.

Comment: Please don't try to put highlighting in code blocks. `**` already has special meaning in Python.

Comment: The NumPy tutorial introduces multidimensional indexing [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating).

Comment: For your first question, what are you asking exactly? The code's incomplete, so we're not going to be able to give a sensible answer. And what are you confused about exactly? We're not going to go through every little bit. Please read [ask] then ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. If you want to understand the language syntax, you should try to follow a tutorial, or directly ask an instructor, or try Reddit or Quora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: `board[r,:]` selects row `r` from the numpy array `board`.

Long version: `board` is a numpy array. You can index it, i.e. access parts of it at a time. How this is done is described in detail in the [link that wjandrea provided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating). Such indexing is exactly what is happening here: `board[r,:]` will select only those elements in row `r`. `:` means that all columns are selected. Taken together, this will simply select row r. You could for example select only the 2nd to 5th column of row `r` by `board[r,1:5]`.

Finally, `list()` converts that row from a numpy array to a python list.